# Unable to find links using selenium in python?

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am scraping a webpage using selenium. I first find the link I want and then click on it and download it(Link is pdf). What happens is sometimes I am able to do so, but sometimes selenium says that link not found. I suppose that it is due to the page not loading properly. What can I do about this and am I in the right direction?

This is my previous code:

```
for b in source_code_2.find_all('a', href=True):
    if b.has_attr("title"):
        if(b['title']=='Click here to download'):
            urllib2.urlretrieve(full_url)
```

now i want to do it using selenium and element. How can I do this?

Comment: I would suggest using either an [implicit wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#implicit-waits) or [explicit wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/waits.html#explicit-waits). Explicit waits can wait for an element to appear and if it doesn't you can try and refresh afterwards.

Comment: I am already using implicit wait still no help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should use explicit wait to tell selenium to wait until specific element loads properly , In python you can use explicit wait in following way :

```
  element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "yourElement"))
```

OR

```
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(
    EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "yourElement"))
    element.click()
```

You just need to replace your element ID in above code and you can change 20 seconds to 30 ,40 as per your need. So meaning of above code is your webdriver will wait until 20 seconds to find that specific element.

Comment: The problem is that I have title of the anchor tag which I need to search...can you tell how can I do this by using explicit wait or some reference links

Comment: ok so how you are finding elememt? By linktext? or by tagname?

Comment: Can you please share your code by update your question please?

Comment: Done! how can I look for title of the element?